# Accidentally moved some files out of Library, how can I work out where they came from so I can put them back?

Tags: macos, osx-el-capitan

I inadvertently moved two folders out from somewhere inside /Library (at least I think that's where they were).

One folder is named FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA000000F8 and contains about 36 .playlist files that appear to be related to various applications.

The other is named 4y, contains one folder named m1f9tls52fs2gytfbr7wz0p40000gn, which in turn contains four folders named O, C, Cleanup At Startup and T. The O, C, and T directories contain lots of stuff, 750 MB in all.

Can anyone tell me where these are supposed to go? I am a bit disturbed that if I re-boot, these things will be missed and I'll have problems.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For future info,  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Z</kbd>   immediately after the *oops* would have returned them. It's likely too late now.

Best guess would be that '4y' & its contents belong in `/private/var/folders`
based on...

Your top folder is a 2-character combination, & not zz.
Inside that is your long hash, then inside that, O, C, T & Cleanup at Startup.
which is the standard folder hierarchy in there.

You are a lot luckier on FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA000000F8 as that folder only occurs in one place
`/private/var/db/BootCaches`
It will share that location with another long hash folder, an alias to PreheatedUser & a couple of other playlist files.

The OS should actually have stopped you from moving any of these, & if you insisted & Authorised it would have, by default, copied rather than moved them - so there is every chance that the originals are still in place. Leave them if everything matches, only move them back if they are missing or distinctly different.

And, just for future reference, `private/var/` is really not a place to be playing in, if you don't know what you're doing. `/private/var/folders` is one of the only ones you can get away with any manual alterations all.

Comment: Thanks for your info. I found both places. I cleverly removed the folders from both places (yes, it required authorisation). /private/var/folders has a replacement folder created at about the time I deleted the previous one, but with much less stuff in it. Should I replace it with the one I moved out?

Comment: You're going to have to do a bit of 'suck it & see' guesswork. The old one will be more complete, but the new one will have the latest data. I'm not sure how they may interplay if you interleave the newest bits of each, so you're gonna have to just make a play for old/new/manually interleaved. Just make sure your time machine is up to date in case of disasters ;-) `p/v/folders` is a safer area to be playing in, I really don't know what happens if you play in where the .playlists are.

Comment: ...or just restore them from an existing Time Machine, which may be safer